# Django - need to split a table across multiple locations

Tags: django

I have a Django project to track our company's restructuring projects. Here's the very simple model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Employee(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    employee_id = models.IntegerField()
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    severance = models.IntegerField()
```

Due to regulations in some European countries, I'm not allowed to keep employee-level severance information in a database that sits on a box outside of that country.

In Django, how do I manage the need to have my Employee table split across multiple databases based on an Employee attribute (i.e. country_code) in a way that doesn't impact anything else in the project (e.g. views, templates, admin)?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: OT: "I'm not allowed to keep employee-level severance information in a database that sits on a box outside of that country."  This has to be one of the most ridiculous regulations out there.  Don't pay attention to the security of the box, just where it sits in the world.

Comment: Well, they also pay attention to the security of the box. It's just that they view having it stored in the U.S. as being an export of personal sensitive information. I'm not crazy about it either, but legislatures have been known to do worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out Django's [multiple database support](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) - you could keep your Employee information in a database based on the country_code attribute, although it might take some hacking to make your `using` statements work correctly when you're querying. Will you know what `country_code` you're working with when it comes time to query an `Employee`?

Comment: I don't think I'll ever query by country_code. It's more that when people use a (future) app to add a person to a restructuring project, the ORM layer will need to know where to place the record. But I may have to query by country_code ... that's just not in our use cases right now.

Comment: In that case, I think you're (probably) fine using multiple databases - you'll need to write some code to handle putting things into the right database when a model gets saved, but you should be fine otherwise.

Comment: Great. I took a look at the multi DB support. I think that'll get me where I need to go.